# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 6 unexpected ' R'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using RIGHT function in where clause but it is throwing error unexpected 'R'. Could you please help on below

select * from table where RIGHT(DATE, 10) ='2020-07-26'

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is valid SQL.  Is there more to the query that you have omitted?

```
with tbl as (select $1 DATE from values ('2021-01-01'))

select * from tbl where RIGHT(DATE, 10) ='2021-01-01';

DATE
2021-01-01
```

Comment: with cte as 
(SELECT max(MFP_LOAD_TS) as MFP_LOAD_TS FROM  DEV_DL2_INSURANCE_RQ.ANNUITIES.OPERATIONS_LC3PD_FEE 
 where RIGHT( MFP_FILE_ID, 10 )='2021-07-26'
)
select MFP_LOAD_TS from cte

Comment: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 3 at position 6 unexpected ' R'. syntax error line 3 at position 14 unexpected 'MFP_FILE_ID'. syntax error line 3 at position 31 unexpected '='.

Comment: Also MFP_FILE_ID Is varchar do I need to cast as date value is "1628025367-LC3PD_FEE-20210730122830-2021-07-26"

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved as there is special character in between where and Right

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to produce the same error when I put an invisible character between WHERE and RIGHT keywords. So there must be an invisible character causing this error.

As a workaround, try to re-write the query from scratch, or delete all spaces between keywords and put spaces again.

Comment: Ah I didn't see your answer when posting my response Jaswanth!